# Is there a Visual Studio equivalent to Eclipse's Local History?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

The Eclipse IDE has a [nice feature](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm) that automatically logs file revisions and you can view them anytime by right-clicking on a file and clicking on `Compare With` -> `Local History...`.

Is there an equivalent to this in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an equivalent feature for local history.

However, if you're using TFS, there is support in the IDE for getting history of files (though this is commited/checked history).

Many other version control systems also have plugins for Visual studio which provide this type of functionality.  For example, [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/documentation) provides an "HG History" command which shows the version history in the Mercurial repository.

Comment: You're right, with TFS click right on the file and choose **View History**. After it's similar to Eclipse IDE

Comment: I don't know why this answer is accepted - the described history is not "local" like Eclipse's Local History, it's a history of what was checked in/committed. Very different thing.

Answer (score 17):

Some more updated options:

Every save is stored in a git repository.  You can use existing git tools to look at the history:

[autogit](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45a3d62b-955e-43cb-9d91-255a837d5f35)

This extension provides a custom local history viewer:

[Local History for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/226c2108-9da9-407d-b90d-9783040d27b8)

Comment: Promising, but those extensions are only available with VS for Windows, not VS for Mac. Would be great if that feature was part of VS itself.

Comment: "Would be great if that feature was part of VS itself" I find myself thinking that a lot...

Answer (score 5):

[Local History for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/226c2108-9da9-407d-b90d-9783040d27b8) is similar to Eclipse or IntelliJ's local history feature. It works with Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.

Answer (score 3):

There is not natively in Visual Studio but what about [Visual Local History](http://vlh2005.codeplex.com/). It has the option to 'Compare with last version'. It should work well for VS 2005, 2008 and with some extra configuration for 2010.

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019 [VSHistory](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KenCross.VSHistory) extension: maintains the history of files in your Visual Studio projects every time they are saved. Any saved version can be viewed or a diff with the current version can be displayed