# Is there a way to save files when they are overwritten by undo?

Tags: tfs

I just lost a few hours of work because I did an undo and get latest changes. I tried using a decompiler to get the code back but the dlls were replaced on the get latest changes.

Would it be possible to have tfs or visual studio save changes locally when I do an undo? I can periodically clear out the directory on my own so it doesn't get huge.

Answer (score 1):

Undo asks "are you sure?". Don't click "Yes" if you aren't. Anyway, see your [AutoRecover directory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/02/14/did-you-know-where-visual-studio-saves-auto-recovered-files-in-the-case-of-an-unexpected-shutdown-151.aspx), but that's cleared on each successful save.

See [Is there a Visual Studio equivalent to Eclipse's Local History?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018575/is-there-a-visual-studio-equivalent-to-eclipses-local-history) for some alternatives.

Comment: Well I thought I was sure. On second thought I could just have it run a console app on every build that copies the files over.

Comment: Yeah you could create a pre build script that xcopy's your source files to a timestamped directory. Be sure to clean up too.

Answer (score 0):

you can download this extension.
[Visual Studio History Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AronDCurzon.LocalHistoryforVisualStudio)

And run it, restart your visual studio. It keeps your changes, when you undo any item, that is a change. Therefore it keeps your changes before from undo.