# Changes in the project deleted after commiting to a remote repository of team member in Bitbucket

Tags: git, laravel-5, version-control, bitbucket

I am a new git user. i am working with my team in a laravel web application project. First i cloned the project in my local machine. then i made some changes. i have read and write access to the team repository in Bitbucket where there is a branch 'mybranch' beside master branch. i had to commit my changes to this mybranch. In order to commit to mybrance, i switched the branch by using

```
git checkout mybranch
```

then i got following message

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkou t: resources/views/aview.blade.php Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches. Aborting
```

then i used following command

```
git checkout -f mybranch
```

then i commited the files like following

```
git add .
git commit -m "my changes" 
git push origin mybranch
```

It committed my controller and view files of the project to mybranch of the repository of bitbucket, but other configuration files of the project were not committed. More importantly, when i switched to master branch and tried to access my codes in local machine, i found all my changes are disappeared. now i only have the project files which was cloned before from the repository. 
Can anyone tell me what went wrong here and how to recover my changes again ?
Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: If you committed your changes to mybranch, then checked out master, your changes would not be on master unless you now merge mybranch into master (something that could be wrong btw so don't do this just because I wrote this comment). Can you explain more about these changes you lost and why you expect them to be on master?

Comment: the repositor which contains master and mybranch is owned by my team. i cloned the project from the master branch, made changes and had to commit to mybranch. now i want to work in my machine as usual to continue my development. but after the commit, i lost my changes. and all the changes are not in mybranch. some files were not committed to mybranch

Comment: Well, you did explicitly ask git to overwrite them, could that be it?

Comment: i used git checkout -f mybranch to switch to mybranch where i had to commit my changes

Comment: And `-f` was the response to the error message git previously gave you, where it said that it would overwrite some local changes. You using `-f` explicitly told git, yes, sure, go ahead and overwrite my local changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did

```
git checkout -f mybranch
```

you told Git to force checkout `mybranch`, and to overwrite any local changes which would be overwritten in the process.  It appears that you have nuked some of your work, and there may not be a fix.

Here is what you could have done to avoid this:

```
git stash               # stash your working directory
git checkout mybranch   # switch to mybranch
git stash apply         # now bring back your working directory
git commit -m '...'     # commit your work on your branch
```

For future reference, be wary of your working directory as it is quite possibly the most vulnerable data.  It is relatively hard to mess up with commits, but the working folder is another story.

With regard to the `master` branch, you never committed this work on that branch, and hence you won't find the changes there.

Comment: so there is no way to recover it? i have to write the codes again ?

Comment: The config files which you report missing were likely overwritten.  There is one option: If you are using a modern IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, then your config files may have a local history.  You could check that history and possibly ressurrect the files.

Comment: i am using VS Code

Comment: VS = Visual Studio?  Can you check your local history for one of the files whose changes got wiped?

Comment: @Rah [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018575/is-there-a-visual-studio-equivalent-to-eclipses-local-history).  It appears that VS does _not_ have a local file history.  So, your work may not be recoverable.  Follow the answers given here to see how to avoid this in the future.

Comment: there is Git History in VS Code. i found the files which were committed to repo

Comment: Great...then see if you find a version dated before you did the checkout.

Comment: it has list of commits, but there is no version. each commit has bunch of files

Comment: No...you're looking at the _Git_ history, not the local history.  This is consistent with what I read in the documentation (hence I was surprised when you told me you found local history).  Painful mistakes are the ones you will remember the most.  Study the answers here so that this never happens again.

Comment: i said Git History. i can't find  local history. yes you are right. it is painful lesson

Comment: are you talking about this local history ? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AronDCurzon.LocalHistoryforVisualStudio

Answer (score 0):

Your changes were committed to `mybranch` that's why they're not in the `master` branch. If you want those changes in your master branch, you can do `git merge mybranch` while you're in the `master` branch. Next time you encounter the error message that you posted, you can do `git stash` before you try to checkout the other branch. Then you can just run `git stash pop` afterwards.

Comment: but all files were not committed to mybranch. some (configuration files ) were not committed to the branch. they are simply disappeared. how can i recover them ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't recovery it back since you were not committed the changes on `master` and checkout to `mybranch` by default.

Before switching to other branches, the changes on the current branch should be committed. If you try to switch to another branch while the changes is not committed on the current branch, git will hint you (as you met):

> ```
> Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout
> ```

But if you checkout to another branch by force (`git checkout -f`), git will discard the uncommitted changes on current branch.

Comment: but why some files were not committed to mybranch ?

Comment: you said i should have committed my changes to master branch before switching to mybranch. but i have read access to master branch; and read and write access to mybranch. can i commit my changes to master branch without having write access ?

Comment: When you at `master` branch, if you changed the files which have already managed in `master` branch, the changes will be lost when you force switching to `mybranch`. If you create new files which were not managed in `master` branch before, after force switching to `mybranch`, the new created files will be committed in `mybranch`. For your situation, it seems you changed the files which have already managed by `master` branch.

Comment: Even you only have read access to master branch on bitbucket, you can still commit on master branch. the read access will stop you to push your local master branch to bitbucket. You just need to cherry-pick/rebase the commit on `master` branch to `mybranch` and then push `mybranch` to bitbucket.