# Is there a way to undo `git reset --hard HEAD~1`?

Tags: git, github

I have a project where I am using git. My code has not been pushed to a server. It was on my local machine only.

I want to undo the last commit, so I executed `git reset --hard HEAD~1` But that command deleted the files from the project instead of undoing the last commit. How can I undo the `git reset --hard HEAD~1` command to my work isn't lost?

When I executed the `it reset --hard HEAD~1` I got `HEAD is now at 7a524b86f not sure`

Comment: The problem is that my code is not on the server. It was on my local machine only

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: If your change made only on client, you cannot come back.

Case 2: If your change made has on server, you didn't push, therefore, you can get back.

Case 3: If your change made on server, you pushed, therefore, you can get back.

Case 4: Your commit has exists on another branches, you can `git cherry-pick` come back.

Trick: If you use IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm, PyCharm, you can use feature local history to get back.

Comment: The changes were on my local machine only! please tell me I did not loose 2 weeks worth of work!

Comment: You cannot get back, because it stands on client, no exist on server.

Comment: does that delete all the files from my local PC? Is there a temp place it get placed in? Lots of code will be lost of I can't get it back. I am using visual studio

Comment: No out-of-the-box local history feature for Visual Studio IDE, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018711/3728901 .

Comment: If you didn't commit the code, it's gone.